# Why won't reloadData() refresh the view?

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBAction func btnDeleteCell(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let UC = UserControllers()

    UC.deleteSocialPlatform(indexRow)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.parentCollectionView!.reloadData()
    }

    print(indexRow)
}
```

The `btnDeleteCell` function is inside of my collectionviewcell class whereas the `parentCollectionView` is set when creating the cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell: SocialPlatformCollectionViewCell

    //if is first element of array
    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        cell = cvSocialPlatform.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCell", for: indexPath) as! SocialPlatformCollectionViewCell

        cell.setupCommon("socialmedialinkgrey", "defaultCell")
        cell.setupbtnInfoText("Add new link")
        cell.parentCollectionView = self.cvSocialPlatform
    }
    else
    {
        cell = cvSocialPlatform.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AddedCell", for: indexPath) as! SocialPlatformCollectionViewCell

        cell.setupCommon("socialmedialink", "addedCell")
        cell.setupInfoTextStr(userSocialPlatform[indexPath.row])
        cell.setupIndex(indexPath.row)
        cell.parentCollectionView = self.cvSocialPlatform
    }

    return cell
}
```

Whenever the user clicks on the delete button on a specific cell, the respective text array will be deleted, and the delete process on the firebase works, but somehow the collection view won't refresh itself in the view controller. Am I doing something wrong here?

delete function in `UserControllers`:

```
func deleteSocialPlatform(_ indexRow: Int)
{
    let userRef = dbManager.databaseRef.child("users").child(dbManager.currentUserID!)

    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

    var socialplatformArray = value?["socialplatform"] as! Array<String>

    print(socialplatformArray)

    socialplatformArray.remove(at: indexRow)
    let newValue = ["socialplatform": socialplatformArray]
    userRef.updateChildValues(newValue)    
}
```

Comment: Is the value actually being deleted from the array and update operations are being completed?

Comment: yes, the data in firebase is being deleted and updated successfully

Comment: The array you are referring as a datasource is "userSocialPlatform" which i see is not being used anywhere in your delete function.. You are deleting the information from the database but the modified set of items are not loaded to the array

Comment: SocialPlatformArray is a local variable and is destroyed as soon as the function has completed execution.. You are modifying that data but that data is not assigned back to the data source which is "userSocialPlatform"

Comment: ah, i think i kind of get it, probably is it because the array used in generating the cell in the view controller does not change?

Comment: Correct! Datasource needs to be assigned the modified values to reflect after reload is being called. If you will restart your app with the same source.. you will see the change as the data from db will get loaded as soon as the view is initialized but unless you assign the new set, datasource remains unmodified and results will be shown accordingly

Comment: ok thanks, I will figure it out to send the modified array back to the data source

Comment: I have posted the answer below.. let me know if it work!

Answer (score 0):

```
 func deleteSocialPlatform(_ indexRow: Int, completion:@escaping(Array<String>) -> ())
    {
        let userRef = dbManager.databaseRef.child("users").child(dbManager.currentUserID!)

        userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        var socialplatformArray = value?["socialplatform"] as! Array<String>

        print(socialplatformArray)

        socialplatformArray.remove(at: indexRow)
        let newValue = ["socialplatform": socialplatformArray]
        userRef.updateChildValues(newValue)
        completion(socialplatformArray)

        }

    }
```

```
 @IBAction func btnDeleteCell(_ sender: UIButton) {


        let UC = UserControllers()
        let parentViewController = PatientPersonalInfoViewController()

        UC.deleteSocialPlatform(indexRow)
        {
            (socialplatformArray) in

            parentViewController.userSocialPlatform = socialplatformArray

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.parentCollectionView!.reloadData()
        }

        print(indexRow)


    }
```

Comment: @akhilesh sharma can you kindly look at it why it still wont work?

Comment: It is not working because it is not the same object that you are accessing the property of, The value of the parentViewController must not be instantiated instead it must access the value which already exists on the heap. Do you have this code anywhere on version control so that i can see it ??

Comment: sorry currently I dont have it since it is a very small project for my assignment. Is there anyway to access the userSocialPlatform directly in the view controller? the btnDeleteCell resides in collection view cell class  which is a separated file from the view controller

Comment: Its hard to tell because i cannot see the project setup.. There are multiple ways to access this information but i need to know the relationship between the controllers and how they are communicating.. UserController is the one in which this method for delete is defined ? Does PatientPersonalInfoViewController leads to UserController or it is a standalone functionality?

Comment: yes, the deleteSocialPlatform function resides in UserController, which is a separate individual file. The PatientPersonalInfoViewController is simply just a viewcontroller class (a seperate cocoatouch file)

Comment: How are you getting to the UserController? Is this via a segue on storyboard or you are calling it out programmatically from PatientPersonalInfoViewController?

Comment: The btnDeleteCell resides in a collectionviewcell class file , which is another separate file to setup the cell of the collectionview in PatientPersonalInfoViewController

Comment: im calling the usercontroller from the delete button in collectionviewcell class

Comment: not from the PatientPersonalInfoViewConntroller itself

Comment: I would suggest that if you can have repo on github it will be easier for me to debug and provide you a legit answer..

Comment: @AkhileshSharma sorry , i was busying just now , can you provide me ur github username or email? i just uploaded to github